# Showing that the limit of non-eigenvector goes to infinity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $3$ by $3$ real matrix with the triple eigenvalue $1$. Also, further suppose its eigenspace corresponding to $1$ is only of dimension $1$. Thus, we can find a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, denoted by $v$. $w_1$. $w_2$ where $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

Then I have to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|A^n w_1\|=\lim_{n \to \infty} \|A^n w_2\|=\infty$.

How is this possible? I do not have any idea how the norm goes to infinity...Could anyone please help me?

Comment: If $A$ has a triple eigenvalue, doesn't its eigenspace have to have dimension $3$? In fact, doesn't $A$ have to equal $I$?

Comment: Pick a basis such that $A$ is in Jordan normal form. What is going to happen?

Comment: @TonyK I guess it is meant as the algebraic multiplicity as an eigenvalue of 1 is 3 and the geometric multiplicity is equal 1. In other words, you get a Jordan block of size 3.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: OK, that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry for being equivocal, Severin Schraven's remark is precisely what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theorem is correct. Without loss of generality and by using [Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition), we can write the most general form of matrix $A$ as$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$Since the eigenspace of $A$ has dimension $1$, and the eigenvector is $v=\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{bmatrix}$ therefore the following set of equations$$\begin{bmatrix}1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{bmatrix}$$must set two of $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ equal to zero. Since the set can be reduced to$$av_2+bv_3=0\\cv_3=0$$therefore we can have $v_1\ne0$ and $v_2=v_3=0$. The only case this happens is when$$a,c\ne 0$$. Therefore the only eigenvector of $A$ becomes $$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$Now take $w_1=\begin{bmatrix}0\\w_{12}\\w_{13}\end{bmatrix}$ and $w_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\w_{22}\\w_{23}\end{bmatrix}$ where $w_2\ne kw_1$. One can prove using induction that$$A^nw_1=\begin{bmatrix}naw_{12}+nbw_{13}+{n(n-1)\over 2}acw_{13}\\w_{12}+ncw_{13}\\w_{13}\end{bmatrix}\\A^nw_2=\begin{bmatrix}naw_{22}+nbw_{23}+{n(n-1)\over 2}acw_{23}\\w_{22}+ncw_{23}\\w_{23}\end{bmatrix}$$Since $a,c\ne 0$, it is easy to check that$$||A^nw_1||\to \infty\\||A^nw_2||\to \infty$$$\blacksquare$

**P.S.**

The general form of $A$ has been chosen upper-triangular since from the Schur decomposition and for any arbitrary vector $v$ we have $$||A^nv||{=||QU^nQ^Hv||\\=||QU^nw||\\=||U^nw||}$$where $w\triangleq Q^Hv$ and $U$ and $Q$ are upper-triangular and unitary respectively.

Comment: Certainly $A$ could be not of the form you wrote, so you cannot claim this is "the most general form" for the matrix $A$. If you mean you apply a change of basis (similarity) to modify the given $A$, then you should say so, and explain why this makes no difference. Also Schur decomposition is something for _complex_ matrices in my book.

Comment: When $A=QUQ^H$ I used $$||Av||=||Uv||$$where $U$ is upper-triangular and then I proved it for any sort of basis. Also I said it first **without loss of generality this is the most general form**

Comment: I added some more details. It is not in fact the triangle inequality. I just substituted $w_1=w_{11}e_2+w_{12}e_3$ to conclude

Comment: That was my mistake. I edited the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Wlog we can assume $A$ to be in Jordan normal form and the basis is the standard basis. We have
$$ A= I + N$$
where
$$ N= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0& 0 &0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Then $N^3= 0$ and we get $A^n= I + n N + \binom{n}{ 2}N^2$. Thus
$$ A^n e_2 = \begin{pmatrix} n \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
and
$$ A^n e_3 = \begin{pmatrix} \binom{n}{2} \\ n \\ 1\end{pmatrix}. $$
Hence, the norms blow up.

Comment: I would upvote this answer if it avoided use of the base $W$ logarithm.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen As an analyst I like my logarithms (not necessarily in base $W$ though). Jokes apart, I do not see the point of clouding the idea by carrying along some change of basis matrices. Especially as the OP seems to be on a level where can easily do the reduction himself (someone that is asking questions about Fourier transforms can probably do a change of basis himself).

Comment: On the other hand one could argue that if OP had seen the reduction, he might have asked the reduced question, and would probably then have been able to answer as well. But that's just guessing. The reduction is a bit subtle though; to not change the norm, and orthonormal base change is called for (which in this case is possible). Anyway enough of being nasty, I'll give you +1.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I am a bit confused by your last comment. If I denote the change of basis by $U$ such that $A = U^{-1} (I+N) U$, then $A^n = U^{-1}(I + n N + \binom{n}{2} N^2) U$. But $Uv_1=e_2$ and $Uv_2 = e_3$. So the only thing one really needs to know is that in finite dimensions all the norms are equivalent to conclude (as the norm is not specified we kind of need to know that anyway). I don't understand why I need the change of basis to be orthonormal.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Actually I was wrong. Your answer shows that one does not need the equivalence of norms...

Answer (score 4):

More generally, let $\lambda$ be a (multiple) eigenvalue of $A$ and let $w$ be a member of the generalised eigenspace of$~A$ for$~\lambda$ (so $(A-\lambda I)^kw=0$ for some$~k\in\Bbb N$), but not an eigenvector (so $k=1$ will not do: $(A-\lambda I)w\neq0$). Write $N=A-\lambda I$, and fix the minimal $k$ such $N^kw=0$; then $[w,Nw,N^2w,\ldots,N^{k-1}w]$ are linearly independent, so a basis of a subspace, and this subspace is of dimension at least$~2$. We can apply the binomial theorem to $(\lambda I+N)^n$ (since $I$ commutes with $N$) giving
$$A^nw=(\lambda I+N)^n(w)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\binom ni\lambda^{n-i}N^iw,$$
with the expansion being cut off at $i=k$ due to $N^kw=0$. But this is an expansion on the mentioned basis. Clearly the coefficient $\binom ni\lambda^{n-i}$ of this expansion for any $0<i<k$ diverges as $n\to\infty$ if (and only if) $|\lambda|\geq1$, in particular for $\lambda=1$ of the question. In fact these coefficients grow without bound, and so therefore does any norm applied to $A^nw$.

Comment: +1 For not needing to know which norm we use (without using the equivalence of all norms in finite dimensions).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is the existence of such generalized eigenvectors guaranteed? For example, Let $A$ be a $3$ by $3$ real matrix with the characteristic polynomial $(t-1)(t+1)^2$. Also, the dimension of the eigenspace corresponding to $-1$ is only $1$; i,e. $A$ does not have a basis consisting of the eigenvectors. 

Then, my question is as follows.

Is there a vector $v$ and a positive number $k \geq 2$ such that $(A+I)^kv=0$ but $(A+I)^n \neq 0$ for all positive integers $n$ smaller than $k$?

Comment: It is a fundamental fact that the dimension of the generalised eigenspace for$~\lambda$ equals the multiplicity of$~\lambda$ as root of the characteristic polynomial. So generalised eigenvectors for$~\lambda$ that are not eigenvectors exists if and only if the dimension of the (ordinary) eigenspace for$~\lambda$ is strictly smaller than mentioned multiplicity. In the question that is the case, as it is in the example of your comment (with indeed $k=2$). It is a bit more subtle affair to show that in the question one has $k=3$ for most vectors (and $k=2$ for a more limited set of vectors).